# Convert an array of objects to a vector in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, dimension

I have an array of objects where the array is of length N and the dimension of the object in the array is (1,2048,7,7). I want to convert this array of objects into a vector of dimension (N,2048,7,7). How do I go about this?

Comment: Have you though about using a `numpy.array` object?

Comment: Oh yes, it worked using this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: A vector has only 1 dimension ;) You're talking of an array / matrix.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.